# Flutter: Error: Could not find the currect Provider<>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I'm started learning flutter and BloC, and I have this issue in my code. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix that.

[image]

Without BlocConsumer all works correctly, but I'm need to use Bloc.

That my class.

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<MainPageBloc, MainPageState>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: state.tabIndex,
              elevation: 24,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlue,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
              items: const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: 'Calendar'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car), label: 'Drivers'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car), label: 'Vehicles')
              ],
              onTap: (index) {
                BlocProvider.of<MainPageBloc>(context)
                    .add(TabChange(tabIndex: index));
              },
            ),
            body: bottomNavScreen.elementAt(state.tabIndex),
          );
        });
  }
}

const List<Widget> bottomNavScreen = <Widget>[
  HomePageContent(),
  CalendarPageContent(),
  DriversPageContent(),
  VehiclesPageContent(),
];
```

And MainApp class

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: RepositoryProvider(
        create: (context) => (),
        child: const MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm tried to change create, delete BlockConsumer, play with Provider, but I'm don't found solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide blocs and cubits at top of the widget tree or when showing dialogs or bottom sheets.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: RepositoryProvider(
        create: (context) => (),
        child: const BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => MainPageBloc(),
          child: MainPage(),
        ),
        // Alternatively you could initialize bloc in statefull widget and 
        // use RepositoryProvider.value named constructor.
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

tip : You can use `context.read<E>()` instead of `BlocProvider.of<E>(context)` and for multiple bloc its better to provide them with `MultiBlocProvider` widget.